# Error in complete() from invalid column/object name

Tags: r, dplyr, autocomplete, tidyr, tibble

I have a CSV with three columns: a `Plot`, an integer vector, `Species`, a character vector, and `DBHClass`, an integer vector. The CSV looks like this:

```
##Read in table
library(tidyverse)
PlotData <- tibble(Plot = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), 
                   Species = c("SNAG", "BLC", "AEL", "BASS", "REDO", "REDM", "BASS"), 
                   DBHClass = c(7, 11, 7, 9, 15, 17, 13)) %>% 
  print()
```

Before I reach my issue, I used `cut_width()` on `DBHClass` to make the column appear as so and added another column, `Exp.ac`:

```
#using cut_width()
PlotData <- PlotData %>%
  mutate(DBH2in = cut_width(PlotData$DBHClass, width = 2),
         Exp.ac = 20) %>%
  group_by(Plot, Species, DBH2in) %>% 
  print()
```

I want to use the `complete()` function to extrapolate this table so that every unique observation in the `Species` column is represented in every unique observation in the `Plot` column. From `length(unique(PlotData$Species))`, there are 7 `Species` that I want to have represented in all unique observations of `DBHClass` within all 4 `Plot`'s for a total of 168 rows, hence `group_by(Plot, Species, DBH2in)`. The recommended code I have for the next step is as follows, however, this error is thrown on row 1:

```
#using complete()
PlotData <- PlotData %>%
  complete(Plot, Species, DBH2in,
           fill = list(Exp.ac = 0, DBHClass = 0)) %>%
  group_by(Plot, Species, DBH.2in)

Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = complete(data = dplyr::cur_data(), ..., fill = fill, explicit = explicit)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Plot = 1, Species = "SNAG", DBH2in = "[7,9]".
Caused by error:
! object 'Plot' not found
```

To circumvent this, I tried using `do(complete))` and slighly different arguments. I've found the following argument doesn't throw an error:

```
#using do(complete())
PlotData<- PlotData%>%
  group_by(Plot, Species, DBH2in) %>%
  do(complete(., Plot, Species, DBH2in,
              fill = list(Exp.ac = 20,
                          DBHClass = 0))) %>% 
  group_by(Plot, Species, DBH2in) %>% 
  print()
```

But this only returns 35 rows, and in Plot 1 for example, the only Species that is shown is shown is `Species = "SNAG"`. What could be causing `complete()` to throw this error? I've tried naming `Plot` as an object (because that's what I inferred it wanted) and removed `Plot` to see if the column was an incorrect class, but the same error gets thrown saying that `Species` is not found. Using other related functions like `nesting()` and `expand()`haven't been successful either. Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `group_by` before `complete`. You're missing a `Species` (6 rather than 7) in the example data, so it only returns 120 combos, but the following works:

```r
PlotData %>%
  mutate(DBH2in = cut_width(PlotData$DBHClass, width = 2),
         Exp.ac = 20) %>%
complete(Plot, Species, DBH2in,
         fill = list(Exp.ac = 0, DBHClass = 0))
```